# How to copy some variables from one notebook to another using different kernel?

Tags: notebooks, remote-access

For example,in windows machine there is a variable `testData`

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
```

And I want to copy this variable to my linux machine.

There are **two notebooks(both using Windows platform)**,one use local kernel(*windows*) and another use remote kernel(*linux*).

[image]

I try to transfer it to `ByteArray` then copy and paste.

Have a good idea?

[image]

Comment: You should look for the `DistributeDefinitions` or `SetSharedVariable` and related. These functions share the data from master-kernel to sub-kernels.

Comment: This is exactly the situation where you might want to use a MathLink between your two sessions.

Comment: @Rom38 they are all about parallel.I only want to move data

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [`Network Programming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NetworkProgramming.html) guide to create a socket connection between the two computers and transfer the data that way.

Comment: @Edmund I think you misunderstood what I mean. I'm just opening two notebooks in one computer now.I just want to copy variable from one notebook to another,don't need socket

Comment: Oh, if it is just a one-off manual operation then copy and paste should be fine.

Comment: @Edmund maybe the data is large that it can not just be copied such as in this case

Comment: Formatted expressions in notebooks may or may not embed the data.  [M11.2 will often ask you explicitly if you want to embed it.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e4hq8.png) If you do, then it is copyable.

Comment: @partida are you using sakra's [tunnel package](https://github.com/sakra/Tunnel) to connect your local frontend to the remote kernel (because I thought this was broken in 11.1 & 11.2)

Comment: @partida, Any kernels connected to your math-session can be assumed as parallel. The mentioned functions share the data among all connected kernels. Will you use the namely parallel run on them or not - it is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple solution, you could use [`CloudPut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudPut.html), [`CloudGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudGet.html) and [`CloudObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html).

```
list = RandomReal[1,10];
CloudPut[list, "myRandomList"]
```

Then in the other kernel:

```
CloudGet["myRandomList"]
```

You need to be signed in to the same Wolfram account from both locations.

---

As a more direct method, you could establish a MathLink (WSTP) connection between the two kernels. This method is much more fickle, and not very tolerant to user mistakes.  It also requires that the two computers be able to see each other over the network and be allowed to communicate over the ports mentioned in the link name.

Here's a short example:

[image]

In kernel 1,

```
link = LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

Now `First[link]` will give you the link name as a string. You will need this for the other kernel.

The following call will block until the connection has been established successfully.

```
LinkActivate[link]
```

Now in kernel 2,

```
link = LinkConnect[linkName, LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

`linkName` is what you got from kernel 1. It consists of `port1@ip,port2@ip`. Make sure that the IP address is written in a format that can be used on this second computer to reach the first (i.e. not 127.0.0.1).

```
LinkActivate[link]
```

At this point, the `LinkActivate` call should return on kernel 1 as well.

Now you can send data.  On one kernel, `LinkWrite[link, data]`, then on the other kernel, `LinkRead[link]`.

Reference:

- [Using WSTP to Communicate between Wolfram System Sessions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingWSTPToCommunicateBetweenWolframSystemSessions.html)

Comment: Easier than the CloudPut setup might be to create a ChannelObject. I've passed data from a cloud session to local session like this as a proof of concept.

Comment: It's a possibility ... but I think we have differing concepts of "easy".

Comment: There also are `CloudSymbol["myVar"]` and `PersistentValue["myVar", "Cloud"]` which seem to be designed specifically for this task.

Answer (score 3):

You could encode data into an [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html):

```
(* NOTEBOOK 1 *)

encode = Image[{ToCharacterCode @ Compress @ #}, ImageSize -> {100, 100}] &;

testData = ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}];

encode[testData]   (* copy apparently blank output image *)


(* NOTEBOOK 2 *)

decode = Uncompress @ FromCharacterCode @ First @ Round @ ImageData @ # &;

(* paste image *) // decode
```

> When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume, among the Powers ...

Comment: If copying from one notebook and pasting to another is an option, I like the `SaveToCell` function here: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/save-data-in-notebooks.html

Comment: @JasonB. interesting article